# How to extract a string from a paragraph?

Tags: java, regex, text-extraction

```
A 24-year-old youth died on the spot, after his motorcycle
 rammed a divider near Golf market on <LOCATION>BelAir</LOCATION> road 
 Thursday night. The deceased has been identified as
 John(24) hailing from <LOCATION>UK</LOCATION>.

He was originally from <LOCATION>Usa</LOCATION>.
```

The sentences are 2 different paragraphs. I want the output to look like:

```
Para 1:BelAir 
       UK

Para 2:Usa
```

I have identified the regex for tags as:

```
<(?<tag>\w*)>(?<text>.*)</\k<tag>>
```

and for paragraphs as:

```
(\n|^).*?(?=\n|$)
```

Is there any way to combine these? Or maybe should I use a split?

Comment: Is this embedded in some sort of HTML or other markup, or is it standalone?

Comment: no its standalone. Actually its the output of stanfords ner tagger

Answer (score 0):

Check if String starts with '\n'

```
while(){//read line
   if(string.startsWith("\n")==false){
     // your regex expration for tags
     // store it in a list
   }
   else{
     // add a null in a List 
   }
}
```

so your list looks like

```
BelAir
US
Null
USA
```

So after each null there is a new Para

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "A 24-year-old youth died on the spot, after his motorcycle " +
            "rammed a divider near Golf market on <LOCATION>BelAir</LOCATION> road" +
            " Thursday night. The deceased has been identified as  John(24) hailing from <LOCATION>UK</LOCATION>." +
            "\n He was originally from <LOCATION>Usa</LOCATION>.";
    String [] paras=str.split("\n"); //Divide the string into two paragraphs
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<LOCATION>(.*?)</LOCATION>");
        for(int i=0;i<paras.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Para "+(i+1)+": ");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(paras[i]);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
```

The output would be

```
Para 1: BelAir
UK
Para 2: Usa
```

Comment: thing is, I cant manually put a \n. Im reading the contents from a text file and i want to recognise all the places from each paragraph